# Xcode 7, iOS 9 and Swift 2.0 makes the life cycle of the ViewController very weird

Tags: ios, swift

1. In Swift 2.0, I push a ViewController ,and the VC is init from the Xib,The problem is coming：the VC load is very slow. If I do something in the VC’s ViewDidLoad, the VC display may need 5 second Or longer.
2. IOS 9 before using SizeClass, the VC view’s size is correct in viewWillAppear, but in iOS 9, view'size is actually 600 * 600 in ViewWillAppear and only in ViewDidAppear to get the correct size, now a lot of operations can not be written inside, can not be written in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear , can only be written in ViewDidAppear.

Answer (score 2):

You better use [viewWillLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) instead. viewWillAppear is not recommended for frame related operations.

Comment: Not at all. `viewDidLoad` is called once per VC, and is nice place to initialize some translated labels that won't change for example.

Comment: i need add some subviews in  viewWillLayoutSubviews ,but this method called multi times，How to solve this problem?

Comment: `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times for good reason - if you change orientation for example your subviews will be "layed" out again with different dimensions which you may need to respect. In order to solve only one problem you could have boolean flag or use dispatch_once.